# Do proficiency bonuses continue increasing after level 20?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-advancement, proficiency

In higher level games shown in the DMG it shows ways to increase ability scores, gain feats or gain an epic boon after gaining 30000 XP.

Though unlike other leveling factors proficiency bonuses after level 20 are not stated.

**So do they increase after a certain number of levels?**

Comment: related: [Do you "gain" a level after getting 30000XP in the late game?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80706)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since the level cap is now 20, there really aren't any "levels" after that. Proficiency bonuses top out at level 17 with +6. After that it's boons or the other advancements you noted.

Answer (score -2):

## No, but that's not to say that they can't.

5th edition doesn't technically have any level progression after 20th. All of the things that the DMG recommends - boons, ability score increases, additional feats - happen once you gain 30,000 additional experience.

That being said, if you are a DM and you want to create a structure for epic levels (or levels beyond 20th), I would recommend increasing the character's proficiency bonus by 1 at 21st level, and by 1 every four levels after that. This fits with the PHB progression - your proficiency bonus starts at +2 and increases to +3 at 5th, +4 at 9th, +5 at 13th, and +6 at 17th.

Comment: Have you tried this? Do you have feedback on how it squares with [bounded accuracy](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/80708/23970)?

Comment: To expand on @nitsua60's comment - we expect homebrew rules to have been tested in practice, otherwise there is no way of knowing that they work as intended.

Comment: @Wibbs No, it has not been tested.

Comment: It's consistent with how monster proficiency bonuses scale, with CR21-24 monsters having a +7 bonus, CR25-28 having +8, and CR29+ having +9.